# Cascade expand and collapse fieldset

Tags: jquery

I need to create a fieldset inside of a fieldset that can expand and collapse when clicked.
I have something that somewhat works but when I expand "Expand 1" it is also expanding "Expand 1.A" when it should not expand "1.A"
Both "Expand 1" and "Expand 1.A" should be able to expand independently.
Here is some very rough code to show what I would like to do.

```
<div>
<fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand 1 [+]</legend>
    <div class="hiders" style="display:none">
        <ul>
            <li>AAA</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
        <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand 1.A [+]</legend>
        <div class="hiders" style="display:none">
            <ul>
                <li>BBB</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
        <legend class="majorpointslegend">Expand 2 [+]</legend>
        <div class="hiders" style="display:none">
            <ul>
                <li>BBB</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is the js using Jquery.

```
$('.majorpoints').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.hiders').toggle();
    var legend = $(this).closest('fieldset').children('legend:first');
    var value = legend.text();
    if (value.indexOf('[+]') >= 0) value = value.replace('[+]', '') + ' [-]';
    else value = value.replace('[-]', '') + ' [+]';
    legend.html(value);
});
```

I am allowed to call external JQuery / JS but I am not allowed to call external "CSS" files.
This is a Visual Studio limitation when debugging XSL and beyond the scope of the question.
Just putting it out there before anyone tells me it would be best to use JQuery mobile since it requires external CSS.

Here is a sample of what I do have working so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/ww3sgcaa/

**EDIT**
I just realized that anytime I click on any text inside the fieldset it expands / collapses but I don't want that. It should only expand / collapse when the legend is clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your JS to this:

```
// click event on the legend rather than the fieldset
$('.majorpointslegend').click(function () {
    // find the next hider to the legend
    $(this).next('.hiders').toggle();
    var legend = $(this).closest('fieldset').children('legend:first');
    var value = legend.text();
    if (value.indexOf('[+]') >= 0) value = value.replace('[+]', '') + ' [-]';
    else value = value.replace('[-]', '') + ' [+]';
    legend.html(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/r2xhedek/